# Possible to cache content on a native PhoneGap/jQuery Android app?

Tags: jquery, caching, dom, cordova

I've made a small Android app using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile. It starts with a native menu which includes options like "Facebook" and "Twitter".
To retrieve the content I use jFeed which loads the content from a RSS feed.

When the user has no Internet, these pages will show no content because the content on these pages is being retrieved via RSS.

Is it possible to cache the content but remove the cache when it successfully retrieves the content? When you use the app, it should try to retrieve the content from the Internet. If the result is empty/false, it retrieves the last information when previous session. But if the result is text/true, the cache should be emptied and resaved with the new content.

That way people will still be able to view the content even when they lost the Internet connection. The next time when they have Internet again, it would retrieve the new online data.

Is this even possible? Is it possible to use some jQuery or PhoneGap command to make a small native cache?

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your RSS fee in a [sqlite DB](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase) or use [localStorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage). You don't need to get real fancy to provide this type of functionality.